# Angular Material design date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm working with angular material design. (https://material.angularjs.org/#/) I have the following piece of code:

```
<md-input-container padding>
  <label>Some date</label>
  <input ng-model="searchQuery.SomeDate" type="date" name="invoiceDate" />
</md-input-container>
```

This gives me a very nice text-box with a datepicker. The user is able to type the date manually or pick a date from the datepicker. Problem is that based on the ui culture the user must type in either dd-MM-yyyy format or MM-dd-yyyy format.

I do not want this. I want to force the dd-MM-yyyy format. But I don't know how to. Do you?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you was try angular date format?

Comment: Try this: <input ng-model="searchQuery.SomeDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'" type="date" name="invoiceDate" />

Comment: Thanks everybody. All suggestions were very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a script from i18n, you can directly set your date param to your country's convention.

This is the list of files : https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/i18n/

Then a simple include will work :

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/i18n/angular-locale_XXXX.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this:

User sees dd/MM/yyyy, but in program it is a date? 
I use it like this:

```
 <span class="input-group">
   <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"  is-open="opened" close-text="Close"/>
   <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
   </span>
 </span>
```

and data sent into model is formated after dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: He uses angular material and not angular ui bootstrap.

Comment: @Apédémak Sorry, for my mistake. But still I hope there is something in code what could help :)